# Importing types from non referenced assembly using MEF

Tags: mef

I have this peice of code:

```
IDocumentParent parent;

var typeofParent = Type.GetType("custom.type", true, true);
```

The problem is that I want to create the type from an assembly that is not referenced.

I do not want to go down the Assembly.Load path, so I was wondering if MEF would be a good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that I want to create the type from an assembly that is not referenced. I do not want to go down the Assembly.Load path, so I was wondering if MEF would be a good solution to this problem?

Yes. Take a look at the [MEF programming guide](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Guide&referringTitle=Documentation).